# Aligning text to always be on the outside of line

Tags: alignment, line

I know how to align text diagonally, but I'm having trouble aligning the text to be always on the outside, as the diagram shows:
http://i38.tinypic.com/rs4zlj.png
The lines will always be positioned as a triangle.

What I get instead is, depending on the angle, text is inside or out (and upside down). Is there any math that can help me out here? I have the angle of every line, if that is helpful at all.

Comment: I think you will need to be more precise in describing your problem. Can you show images of desired and undesired results, for example?

Comment: I already have an image of desired results.